# RSpec: how do I correctly simulate #destroy failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm having a very hard time simulating the failure of a destroy method in my controller.

My controller's destroy looks like this:

```
def destroy
   project = Project.find(params[:id])
   project.destroy

  if project.destroyed?
    render json: {
      project: nil,
      message: "The project was successfully deleted"
    }
  else
    render json: {
      message: "Could not delete project",
    }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

I'm trying to render the json in the else block in my test, but can't get it done. So far the particular test looks like this:

```
describe "DELETE #destroy" do

 let!(:project) { create(:project, :open) }

  context "when invalid" do

   it "returns an error if the project was not deleted" do
     expect(Project).to receive(:find).with(project.id.to_s).and_call_original
     expect(project).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)
     delete :destroy, id: project
   end

 end
end
```

The test either returns the 'happy path' or gives me errors. At the moment:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(project).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)

       (#<Project:0x007f87cf5d46a8>).destroy(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, and explain how I can simulate a 422, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want allow at the start, not expect.  Expect is the assertion part.

```
it "returns an error if the project was not deleted" do
  allow(Project).to receive(:find).with(project.id.to_s).and_call_original
  allow(project).to receive(:destroy).and_return(false)

  delete :destroy, id: project

  expect(Project).to have_received(:find)
  expect(project).to have_received(:destroy)
end
```

I'm assuming you're right with

```
allow(Project).to receive(:find).with(project.id.to_s).and_call_original
```

but I've never seen that before, I would normally do

```
allow(Project).to receive(:find).with(project.id.to_s).and_return(project)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! The expect(project).to received(:destroy) throws an undefined method error.

If I print the response.body to console I still see the 'happy path' result. How does the allow() and_return(false) work?

Comment: Sorry @Iris that should be `have_received`.  Essentially it's in [rspec's mocks](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/basics/allowing-messages). It basically just tells rspec to let the project receive a call to `destroy` and return what we want i.e `false`.  You'll want to add in other assertions to check the message/status.

Comment: Thanks @j-dexx . Figured and tried it, but now I again get that `Failure/Error: expect(project).to have_received(:destroy)

       (#<Project:0x007f89b4fb4a88>).destroy(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments` again :(

Comment: Could that be because I'm not using a double?

Comment: What if you change the allow to be `allow(Project).to receive(:find).and_return(project)`  It shouldn't matter that you're not using a double but a factory girl factory.  I don't think you need the `project.destroyed?` you should just be able to do `if project.destroy`